# MongoDB Search if Value Doesn't Exist In the sub array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**Model:**

```js
const Room = new Schema({
  topic: String,
  messages: [{
    text: String,
    readByUsers: [String] // Array of users Ids, which read this message
  }]
});
```

**Example data:**

```js
{
  topic: 'First',
  messages: [
{
      text: 'First message',
      readByUsers: ['id1', 'id3', 'id2']
    },
    {
      text: 'Second message',
      readByUsers: ['id1', 'id2'] //id3 not read this
    }
  ]
},
{
  topic: 'Second',
  messages: [
    {
      text: 'Third message',
      readByUsers: ['id1', 'id3', 'id2']
    },
    {
      text: 'Fourth message',
      readByUsers: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal - receive **First object**, because **Second message** was not been read by **id3** user (this key not exists in readByUsers array).

Query like:
Search all documents, where some of *messages.readByUsers* not contains specific userId

```js
Model.find(messages.readByUsers: {$nin: [userId]})
```

works only if no one of *messages.readByUsers* not contains id, for example
 `Model.find(messages.readByUsers: {$nin: ['id4']})` - returns both objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) operator which looks for at least one element which satisfies its conditions:

```js
Model.find({messages: {$elemMatch: {readByUsers: {$ne: 'id3'}}}})
```